# Using sed/awk to extract multiple strings from each line

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a file that contains 30million lines(so big file)

On each line I have this kind of data:

```
"title": "some title" (SOME RANDOM DATA) "rank": "1,292,064"
```

I need to extract both the title value and the rank value so:

```
some title:1,292,064
```

Little help? :) I have tried my little heart out and nothing, can only extract one piece of data from each line

Comment: Could you please do let us know if it's a JSON file? If yes then awk/sed are not right ways to do it, jq is more appropriate for it as per experts advice.

Comment: And please, make a proper sample with no `(SOME RANDOM DATA)` in the middle making more harm than good. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with James Brown. We need to know if the fields between quotes can have escaped quotes, and if the RANDOM DATA can contain parentheses or not. We suppose there are no new lines into your fields, albeit surrounded by quotes.

Comment: The reason I put random data in the middle is that the data in the middle is random and not something I could type.. as it's random(special characters and spaces included), 30 million times over.

Comment: Do you know how to do a sed substitution command? Three of them will do the job.

Comment: @beta I don't know how to do that no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except in the case there could be escaped quotes between the quotes, and other tricky stuff like that, I would try this **sed** command to filter your big file:

```
sed 's/^"[^"]*": "\([^"]*\)".*"\(.*\)"$/\1:\2/'
```

Basically, you look for two subgroups `\1` and `\2` containing the fields you want, and you print these separated by a `:`.

In case the string title appears litterally, the regex passed as argument to sed is less ugly:

```
sed 's/^"title": "\([^"]*\)".*"\(.*\)"$/\1:\2/'
```

Even safer, for avoiding side effects from the random data:

```
sed 's/^"title": "\([^"]*\)".*"rank": "\(.*\)"$/\1:\2/'
```

Comment: Still doesnt seem to be working, could you try this exact line:"title": "natural" g4j()K<LS>|S(&"L< "rank": "1,292,06"

Comment: It works. I get `CareNatural Tea Tree Acne Free Essential Set, Natural & Organic:1,292,06` as output.

Comment: Oops? Did you edit your comment while I was testing?

Comment: Anyway, it is also working with the latter input `"title": "natural" g4j()K<LS>|S(&"L< "rank": "1,292,06"`, I get `natural:1,292,06` as output.

Comment: After running your code it works great most the time but I didn't notice that some lines have some random data added onto the end too and its causing it to not output the rank but it outputs random data instead, any way to account for that? If not it's fine as is.

Comment: I edited my solution above in order to avoid that case.

Comment: check this please: "title": "CareNatural Tea Tree Acne Free Essential Set, Natural & Organic" g4j()K<LS>|S(&"L< "rank": "1,292,06"ogbokgbokgobkgok050g5")("

Comment: No match with input `"title": "CareNatural Tea Tree Acne Free Essential Set, Natural & Organic" g4j()K<LS>|S(&"L< "rank": "1,292,06"ogbokgbokgobkgok050g5")("`, which is the correct behaviour, I presume.